# CSS file refuses to link to HTML file

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to the realm of web design, however, I've been having a problem that really has me stumped. My CSS file will not link with my HTML file. I've checked everything(I think). The file paths are identical, I linked the files with the correct syntax, yet it's still not working. I've attached some photos to help you guys get a better understanding of my problem. If you need more info, I'll be happy to provide it.

The first image is the folder I'm keeping the files in. The second one is the syntax I'm using to link the HTML and CSS. And the third and fourth files are screenshots of my editor, with the file paths on top. (And yes, I'm aware the CSS file is empty. But since it wasn't working correctly, I left it blank for now)

[image: Here's where I keep the files.]

[image: Here's the syntax I'm using to link the files.]

[image: File path on my HTML.]

[image: File path on my CSS.]

Comment: Check your webserver's logs to see if there's a request for the css file. What you've shown in the screencaps SHOULD be working, so see what the server is (or isn't) receiving when you load the html file.

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Are you writing this by hand or do you have a code editor like Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you need to force the browser to use the latest styelsheet. You can achieve this by adding a query string in the link.

Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Joe.css?v=1.1" "type="text/css"/>
```

As you can see I've added **?v=1.1** after "Joe.css

Then simply change version number every time you have done some changes in your CSS file. So in this case, when you have updated the CSS file you can change the number to ?v=1.2 and so on. By doing this you are forcing the browser to use the latest css.

But please note that you should only add this to the link not to the actual filename Joe.css - that stays the same.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! This really helped. I'll keep it in mind for future creations of mine!

Answer (score 4):

How do you know its not working if the CSS is empty?

Type `body { background-color: #f0f; }` to test if it's working.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention. No, because every time I tested it, nothing would happen.

Comment: Maybe the code you were typing in was incorrect, for example i just realised I told you to set a background color, when you already have a background image. Do some really basic CSS to ensure.

Comment: I tried styling some basic <p> elements, along with changing the bg color. No luck yet. Should I just redo everything?

Comment: You can see the lists right? Do me a favour and try this:

li { padding: 100px; }

It will immediately become obvious if your CSS is working.
If that still doesn't work, can you create a screenshot of the actual output?

Comment: I can intact see the lists. I've entered your code in my css file. And heres a screenshot of the output: http://i1107.photobucket.com/albums/h393/kfedor/screen-capture-1.png

Answer (score 1):

You should debug your code.

Firstly, replace your `<link>` tag with the following and see if it works:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #000; }
</style>
```

If your background color is changed to black - that's a good sign.
If not, something's wrong with your script or browser.

---

Next, replace the above piece of code with the following:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Create the file `style.css` **in the same directory as your HTML script** and put the following code in it:

```css
body { background-color: #000; }
```

If that doesn't work, something's wrong with your script or browser.

---

btw, try to clear your browser cache.

Comment: The <style> tags work fine. However, I've tried the rest and no luck. I think I'll just start over. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugging tool in a web browser - Firebug in firefox, or the F12 developer tools in IE for example - to see what CSS is being loaded with your web page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using syntax: `body { background-image: url("Joe-Image/Joe-logo.png");}` and are you sure you added the CSS in your html file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link href="./joe.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

I inserted the relative path. You could also try this:

```
<link href="./Joe.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

With upper case j. Perhaps your web server is case sensitive?